# How do I use imhistmatch in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to implement with the matlab function imhistmatch.
So I use following commends.

```
A= imread('example1.jpg')
B= imread('example2.jpg')
C= imhistmatch(A,B)
```

But there is problem like this.
?? Undefined functionor method 'imhistmatch' for input arguments of type 'uint8'

So What am I suppose to do for solve?

Comment: `imhistmatch` is part of the Image Processing Toolbox, is it available?

Comment: What version are you using? `imhistmatch` was introduced with version 2012b

Comment: If you have the toolbox, most likely you have another .m file that is named `imhistmatch.m`. Change the name of that file to something else

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanjs sir, But I think this is happened what I do not casting to uint.

Comment: @kaji ? the function works fine with uin8, I have just tested it in my computer. Before anything else make sure that there is no `imhistmatch.m` in your folder.

Comment: @kaji: What version of matlab and what does `which imhistmatch` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about your question. Are you trying to implement imhistmatch?
Then probably your function is in the wrong folder or you have a typo in the functions name.
use

```
addpath('Pathto/imhistmatch')
```

to ensure that matlab can find your implemented function.

But maybe you want to use the function imhistmatch provided by the image processing toolbox. Then, I guess you don't have the image processing toolbox.
Try

```
ver
```

and check the output. You should find these lines:

```
MATLAB                                                Version X.X        (XXXXX)
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version X.X        (XXXXX)
```

If not, then you may want to buy the image processing toolbox, get a evaluation version or maybe try octave.

On my computer the following works:

```
imhistmatch(ones(10),ones(10))
imhistmatch(ones(10,'uint8'),ones(10,'uint8'))
```

but when I type

```
imhistmatch(ones(10,'int8'),ones(10,'int8'))
```

I get an error:

```
Error using imhistmatch
Expected input number 1, A, to be one of these types:

uint8, uint16, double, int16, single

Instead its type was int8.
...
```

So, if it would be a type problem you would see another error.

Your error is the result of not having the proper function imhistmatch.

Comment: Sorry I have gave you misunderstand I just have modify my question.

Comment: then check for the toolbox

Comment: I'm not sure your answer. What care of this version? I think it just casting problem. But I 'm not sure. I2 = im2uint8(..). Should I have to use converting function?

Comment: I found MATLAB Version X.X (XXXXX) Image Processing Toolbox Version X.X (XXXXX)  when I type the ver.